# Compute the frequency of words using Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a dummy server that is sending text over a socket to my Spark program. I would like the program to then be able to process the text to determine the frequency of a word relative to the amount of words in a `Window`. Below is the code I have tried

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import scala.Tuple2;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class TwitterStream{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("Twitter")
                .setMaster("local[4]")
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g");

        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));

        JavaDStream<String> window = tweets.window(Durations.seconds(6), Durations.seconds(2));

        JavaDStream<String> words = window.flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.split(" ")).iterator());

        JavaDStream<String> window = words.window(Durations.seconds(6), Durations.seconds(2));

        JavaPairDStream<String, Long> pairs = window.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1L));
        JavaPairDStream<String, Long> wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);

        JavaDStream<Tuple2> test = wordCounts.transform(f -> f.map(x -> new Tuple2<>(x._1, x._2/f.count())));

        test.print();

        jssc.start();

        jssc.awaitTermination();

        jssc.stop();
    }
}
```

I initially tried to use the `transform` method on the `WordCounts` object but it resulted in the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext. It could happen in the following cases: 
(1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
(2) When a Spark Streaming job recovers from checkpoint, this exception will be hit if a reference to an RDD not defined by the streaming job is used in DStream operations. For more information, See SPARK-13758.
```

So then I thought I would just try and use the `count` method for the `windows` object and divide it by the number of occurrences of a word but this resulted in an error as count returns a `JavaDStream` and not a long.

```
wordCounts.mapToPair(x -> {return new Tuple2<>(x._1, x._2/wordCounts.count());});
```

The program should be able to print out something like `(test,0.2232), (car,0.1342), ...`

Thanks in advance.